# Cross-network remoting in .NET

Tags: .net, remoting

I'm doing a sample in .NET remoting. I want to know is it possible to exchange data between a computer in my network to a computer in another network?

Comment: You can't exchange data if the other computer is in another network. If you are both connected to the internet have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx

Comment: I'm very saddened by the comments (deleted) on this post... if the question needs work - edit it; don't just attack it. It took a moment only to make this clear...

Comment: @Marc; I like you, you're nice.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you can use .NET remoting between networks (and I suspect it can), there a few things to consider:

- the firewalls may not make it especially convenient
- .NET remoting is deprecated
- .NET Remoting provides no security or intergrity

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.85).aspx):

> This topic is specific to a legacy
>   technology that is retained for
>   backward compatibility with existing
>   applications and is not recommended
>   for new development. Distributed
>   applications should now be developed
>   using the Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF).

Personally, I would look (as suggested) at WCF for your cross-network IPC needs.

Comment: +1. If the question is spam, your answer is chorizo.
Nice to see some respect and cool-headed reactions.

Comment: Added point on security. A .NET remoting endpoint can be used by anyone, if exposed beyond a controlled environment you could get hostile clients trying to break your application.

Comment: Thank you Marc and Richard. I was just looking into .NET Remoting for my next project, but will check out other alternatives.